# If $A$ is a nilpotent matrix is it possible that $\dim(null(A^p))=\dim(null(A^{p+1}))$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

If  $A$ is a nilpotent $n \times n$ matrix (there exists a minimal $k \ge 2$ such that $A^k=0$) is it possible that $\dim(\ker(A^p))=\dim( \ker(A^{p+1}))$ for any $p<k$?

What i know so far is that $k\le n$ (can this bound be improved?) because $P(X)=X^k$ is an annulator polynomial of $A$ and the minimal polynomial $m_A (X)$ of $A$ satisifies $\deg m_A \le n$ as well as $m_A | P$.

Comment: No. Look at the Jordan normal form of $A$. The result is true for any one nilpotent Jordan block; and it will be true for any normal form of several Jordan blocks.

Comment: $A^p$ and $A^{p+1}$ can be put in Jordan form simultaneously. So, it is enough to study a nilpotent Jordan block. A nilpotent Jordan block is zero everywhere except for the diagonal above the principal diagonal, where it has ones. When you power such a block the diagonal of ones shifts up one diagonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to think about it without Jordan form:

Let $A(V)$ denote the image of $A$.
Suppose that $\dim\ker(A^p) = \dim\ker(A^{p+1})$ for some $p$.  It follows that $\dim[A^p(V) \cap \ker(A)] = 0$.  Moreover, 
$A^{p+1}(V) \subseteq A^p(V)$, so
$\dim[A^{p+1}(V) \cap \ker(A)] = 0$.  From this, it follows that $\dim\ker A^{p+2} = \dim\ker A^{p+1}$.

Continuing in such a fashion, we see that $\dim \ker A^{q} = \dim \ker A^p$ for any $q > p$.  So, if $\dim \ker A^p > 0$, then $A$ cannot be nilpotent.